# Why is our MVCSiteMap slow to load in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

We have an Azure Website implemented with C#/MVC/Razor that includes the
[ASP.NET MVC SiteMap provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider)

Since deploying the Azure with a Basic Web Hosting Plan, we have noticed that the SiteMap appears to be slow to initialize. The performance hit comes when this function is first called:

```
SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey(key)
```

In our test Aure environment, this takes about 18 seconds to complete during a logon to our site. Subsequent accesses complete in a few hundred milliseconds, until a period of time passess (not sure what yet) and then the next access has the same 18 second hit.

Our sitemap file has about 250 nodes in it

We have set the Azure Website "ALWAYS ON" setting to "ON".

The same code in my local dev environment is only taking 2 seconds for the initial sitemap load. As far as I can tell, there is no database access happening while the sitemap is loading.

Comment: take a look at some of these steps http://robbincremers.me/2012/02/23/using-windows-azure-caching-service-to-improve-performance-for-your-cloud-services/

Comment: Do you know this to be an approach specifically suitable to the MVCSiteMap, or is it just a general explanation of Azure Caching? Thanks, it looks like a very comprehensive article but I'm struggling to understand why Azure can't load a static XML file of ~31k in under 18 seconds without re-architecting to use a proprietary caching mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

So anyway, it was a false alarm. Upon closer inspection I found that we had an abandoned DynamicNodeProvider that used some inefficient data access logic and resulted in ~8,000 discrete SELECT calls being issued to SQL Azure.

When I took this out, performance returned to normal.

Another good lesson in the importance of cleaning unneeded rubbish out of your codebase.